# Can ASP.Net MVC be used as an API in place of WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a presentation for my company internally to summarize what I've learned about programming and how it relates to .NET, C#, and all of the key concepts companies look for and I'm a little stuck in how to explain API.

I know how API works, I've written many and I know that it's used to transmit data. The definition I stumbled upon is:

"API is Application Programming Interface, a set of definitions, protocols and tools for building application software... Just as a graphical user interface can be used to transfer data back and forth between person and machine, API is used to transfer data back and forth between machine and machine."

Thinking back to examples of reddit.com and other websites, if you append .json to the end of some websites you're making a get to their website and the information is served up in the form of JSON.

Am I right in saying:

"MVC can be used as API, but WebAPI is a pre-defined framework built to make API a lot more efficient, effective and easy to write"?

Comment: Came across this article the other day give it a look. https://medium.com/@sheetsu.com/rest-api-for-dummies-the-store-metaphor-c9e531bcd425 outside of that this question is too broad to be answered properly on this site

Comment: MVC and Web API have been melded together to be pretty interchangable in the newer versions of .net.  Really just depends if you want to serve an html page or just json

Comment: @Nkosi how is this too broad?

Comment: MVC is just a architectural/design pattern so i wouldn't say "MVC can be used as API" rather "ASP.NET MVC framework can be used to build a Web API" or something similar.

Comment: @thunderbird is this better? My question is very specific after you read it -- "Am I correct in making this assumption" but I can see how you think the title might be considered too broad... However at the same time, couldn't you also make the assumptions that "since MVC is an architectural pattern closely associated with Presentation, ALL MVC could be used as APIs"? -- However I do agree that the question title could have been better when I initially posted.

Comment: and @Nkosi you should have posted that, that article is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for! but Peter M. also answered my question more precisely anyway. Great resource though!

Comment: @user3654055 glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

API is a very broad term, which can be used to refer to any programming interface. You could use any HTTP-based system to build an API, so you could also use the ASP.NET MVC framework for it. It probably would make more sense to use a framework specifically meant for building APIs, but strictly speaking your statement is correct.